# How to hook the GEF Editor and TextEditor together in MultiPage Editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

I'm developing an eclipse multipage editor with two pages **Design Page** and **Source Page**, where a design page is a Graphical Editing Framework (GEF) editor and source page is text editor. I want to save the content of GEF editor in XML file(possible by using EMF) and content of text editor page in text file . Can someone give me suggestions about how to hook these two editors in multipage editor,**so that I can read the xml file of gef editor and generate the text in text editor**. I did some examples on multipage editor which contains the gef editor page and a some other page(not a text editor).

Comment: Are you asking about how to have a single class to handle these two pages or?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII yes, a single class which extends MultiPageEditorPart